# Error while building docker image, Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.2:build-image (default-cli) on project

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven

snippet from pom.xml:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                <image>vasanth0202/microservice-${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</image>
                <pullPolicy>IF_NOT_PRESENT</pullPolicy>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Getting this error while building this in eclipse,
Run As-> Maven build -> Goals (spring-boot:build-image -DskipTests) -> Run

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.2:build-image (default-cli) on project currency-exchange-service: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.2:build-image for parameter image: Cannot find default setter in class org.springframework.boot.maven.Image -> [Help 1]

Am i missing something? Please help on this.

Comment: You are probably mixing jars/modules from different Spring Boot versions, leading to this issue.

Comment: I did a mistake in the image tag. image name should be part of <name> tag. 
    <image>
     <name>vasanth0202/microservice-${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</name>
    </image>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a mistake in the image tag. image name should be part of name tag.

After correcting the image tag in pom.xml, image is generated properly.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBAeF.png)